# Determine index of a JS object in array while knowing the object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I determine what the index of an object is within an array?

Take the following setup:

```
var item =  [
        {
            identifier: "id1",
        },
        {
            identifier: "id2",
        },
        {
            identifier: "id3",
        }
];
```

I know what the object value is and that it exists and currrently have it stored like this `currentValue = "id2";`

What i'd like to know is that "id2" equals to (in this case) index 1.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to iterate and check each property

```js
var currentValue = "id2";

var item =  [
        {
            identifier: "id1",
        },
        {
            identifier: "id2",
        },
        {
            identifier: "id3",
        }
];

var index = 0;

item.forEach(function(obj, i) {
    if ( obj.identifier === currentValue ) {
         index = i;
         return false;
    }
});


document.body.innerHTML = index;
```